How can I export a PyCharm run configuration to use in a CI/CD pipeline?
I have a run configuration in PyCharm that allows me to execute all my tests without any issues. I want to use this same configuration in my CI/CD pipeline (e.g., GitHub Actions, GitLab CI/CD, Jenkins, etc.). Is there a way to export the run configuration from PyCharm and adapt it for use in a CI/CD pipeline? Generating a bash script file from the configuration seems to be sufficient.

Speaking in general (any JetBrains IDE), you should see the command that the IDE executes in the console output, at the very start (e.g. see the screenshots here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/test-runner-tab.html ) . But it will not include any additional "preparations" that the IDE is doing behind the scene, like setting up ENV variables, changing working directory etc.
